# Opentracing proper way to inject/extract span context

Tags: java, spring, grpc, jaeger, opentracing

I have 2 applications communicating via grps.
When I try to send a span context, I always get null in ***extracted***.

```
Map<String, String> tracingMetadata = new HashMap<>();
        tracingMetadata.put("trace-id", traceId);
        tracingMetadata.put("span-id", spanId);
SpanContext extracted = tracer.extract(Format.Builtin.TEXT_MAP, new TextMapAdapter(tracingMetadata));
```

Therefore, I send it via metadata in ClientIntercaptor like that.

```
    return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(
        next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
      @Override
      public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
        headers.put(Metadata.Key.of("trace-id", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), traceId);
        headers.put(Metadata.Key.of("span-id", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), spanId);
...
```

When I try to create a context span from this data, it either talks about incompatible types, or context doesn't change. In ***pre*** and ***after*** equal context.

```
private void injectParentContext(Span span) {
    final String traceId = HeadersServerInterceptor.getTraceIdHeader();
    final String spanId = HeadersServerInterceptor.getSpanIdHeader();

    final Map<String, String> contextValues = new HashMap<>();
    contextValues.put("x-b3-trace-id", traceId);
    contextValues.put("x-b3-spanid", spanId);

    final SpanContext pre=span.context();

    tracer.inject(span.context(), Format.Builtin.TEXT_MAP, new TextMapAdapter(contextValues));

    final SpanContext after=  span.context();
  }
```

I tried different ***Format.Builtin*** and ***Adapter***, nothing works.
What am I doing wrong?